# getting an error when converting react component to string

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I've been working with react for a couple months now and I've been doing server side rendering successfully. Recently I started rewriting a personal app with ES6 + Babel. When I try to run `renderToString()` on a react component I get this error:

> renderToString(): You must pass a valid ReactElement.

**some code**

*the component*

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


export class InfoBox extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className='info-box'>
                    Hello
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if(typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    ReactDOM.render(<InfoBox/>, document.getElementById('info-box-mount-point'));
}
```

*express index route*

```
import express from 'express';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom/server';
import InfoBox from '../react-components/info-box/info-box.jsx';

let router = express.Router();
let InfoBoxFactory = React.createFactory(InfoBox);

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', { 
        reacthtml: ReactDom.renderToString(InfoBoxFactory)
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

another question: should I be saving my components as `.jsx` or `.js`? (I'm using `jsx` in the render method of the component for the html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you need import class `InfoBox` from `info-box.jsx` because in `info-box.jsx` there is no [`default export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#Using_the_default_export)

```
import { InfoBox } from '../react-components/info-box/info-box.jsx';
      ^^^       ^^^
```

or add `default` to `info-box.jsx`,

```
export default class InfoBox extends React.Component {}
       ^^^^^^^
```

**Update:**

You can avoid using `createFactory` and just render react component, like so

```
ReactDom.renderToString(<InfoBox />)
```